# How to check is a date (in format dd/mm/yyyy) is already past in DOJO

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to know if a date has already past-by and if it has I would make the input box non-editable.

My input box code is:

```
<input id="inserviceInputId" type="text" value="09/05/2003" name="inserviceInput" style="width:7em">
```

and the Dojo code I have so far:

```
var date1 = new Date;
    dojo.query("[name=inserviceInput]").forEach(function(evnt,i){

    console.log(evnt.value)

    });
```

So, I do get the input box's value here. But the issue is how to subtract the today's date and the date in the value.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `dojo/date/locale` to parse the value into a javascript Date object and then just compare the date objects.

```
require(["dojo/query", "dojo/date/locale"], function(query, locale){

  query("[name=inserviceInput]").forEach(function(node){

    var dtNow = new Date();
    var dtValue = locale.parse(node.value, {
        selector: 'date',
        datePattern: 'dd/MM/yyyy'
    });

    // validation
    if(dtValue < dtNow) {
      // error condition...
    }

  });
});
```

[Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

first, I don't think your syntax is correct. It looks like you are trying to write an event handler ( function(evnt, i) ) instead of doing some action on the value from the node.

I attached some corrected code below, and to explain I added inline comments:

```
dojo.query("input[name='inserviceInput']").forEach(function(node){
   var date1 = new Date();  // get the current date and time

   var date2 = new Date(node.value); // turn the input from the input field into a date

   if (date1>date2) { // compare the two dates, 

     //if the current date is larger than the date from the input field... 
     // do something here  
   }
```

});

Comment: You code is working fine, just one issue is in, my date values in the input box is in dd/mm/yyyy format. I believe because of which the conversion is not happening correct. And I am getting a few incorrect answers also.

Comment: I think the answer below addresses that. One thing I'd look into is using a date picker instead of relying on people to put the correct date format in, or you will be in a date conversion nightmare.